# Counterexample to an Algorithm Complexity Statement

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Say I have the following statement:

> If $f(n) = O(s(n))$ and $g(n) = O(r(n))$, then $f(n) - g(n) = \Theta(s(n) - r(n))$.

What would be a counterexample to this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I could not find something to prove that the statement is wrong

Comment: Well, but what functions did you try for $f$, $g$, $r$, and $s$? Why did that not work? We do want to help you find the solution, not simply solve your homework for you.

Comment: I started to study this subject, I'm looking for help and examples for some questions, if you can not help it well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of counterexamples! $f(n) = n, s(n) = n, g(n) = n, r(n) = n^2$. $f(n) - g(n) = 0 = \Theta(n^2 - n) = \Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: could explain one of these counterexamples

Comment: @GracianoSouza I've explained. Does not clear?